# How do I cast from chrome browser to my chrome cast

Tags: release-juno, google-chrome, chromium

As the title says it simply does not work on elementary os. I've tried it with all my other devices running mac, windows and android and they all work fine.

I'm running Juno and my chrome browser version is 78.0.3904.108. I've also tried chromium, vivaldi brave and opera. Casting with them do not work either.

I've also tried casting with following flags enable and disabled and every combination you can think of:
**Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses**
**Cast Media Route Provider**
**Mirroring Service**

I've also tried mkchromecast but that didn't work either.

Anyone else having these issues or can point me in the right direction.